# JAXBClassLoader loaded by WebLogic referances application class loader and causing leak

Tags: java, jaxb, garbage-collection, classloader, weblogic12c

JAXBClassLoader(Eclipse Moxy Implementation) loaded by WebLogic has referance to my web application class loader (ChangeAwareClassLoader) as parent and so it can load classes in application. But when i redeploy my web application, old context could not be reclaimed by GC because of that.

Here is the image captured from MAT that describes the situation.

[image]

My question is that how can clear referance to application class loader from JAXBClassLoader to make context available for GC.

Comment: i think if i take eclipselink moxy to my application and modify weblogic.xml to load from application, this problem can be solved